# Kendo Grid initialized with Jquery Column Template Not Working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid in html as below

```
<div id="grid">
```

and initializing grid as below

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    sortable: true,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
              {id: 1, name:"x" },
              {id: 2, name: "y" }
            ],
        }),
    columns: [
      { field: "name"},
      { template: '<button class=\'k-button\' ng-click=\'alert("custom1")\'><i class="icon-edit"></i>custom1</button>' },
     ]
});
```

The column template ng-click is not working in this flow, if i changed this to angular style of kendo-grid then it works as expected.

Could you guys help me in Jquery way of Initializing Grid.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try for following code,

instead of attaching event in template, write the attach event in corresponding file.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/jtZgDlvqfOq1oDK7js57?p=preview][1]
```

in HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div kendo-grid 
    k-columns='[
      { template: "<input value=\"click\" type=\"button\" ng-click=\"clickAction()\" />" },
      { field: "name" }
    ]' 
    k-editable="true"
    k-sortable="true"
    k-data-source="gridDataSource">
  </div>

</body>
```

in js part:

```
 $scope.clickAction=function(){
    alert("you click me");
  }
```